# update en mongodb nodejs

Tags: mongodb

estoy tratando hacer un put en mongodb usando el método **findByIdAndUpdate** pero no funciona, no muestra ningún error simplemente no actualiza los datos. Este es mi codigo:

```js
function updateNota(req, res){
  let notaId = req.params.notaId
  let update = req.body
  console.log(update)

  Nota.findByIdAndUpdate(notaId, update, (err, notaUpdated) => {
    if(err) res.status(500).send({message: `Error al actualizar la nota: ${err}`})

    res.status(200).send({ nota: notaUpdated })
  })
}
```

Supongo que el  problema es porque el req.body esta vacio (el console.log no muestra nada). Ojala puedan ayudarme, desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
function updateNota(req, res){
  let notaId = req.params.notaId
  let update = req.body
  console.log(update)

  Nota.findByIdAndUpdate(notaId, update, (err, notaUpdated) => {
    if(err) return res.status(500).send({message: `Error al actualizar la nota: ${err}`})

    if(!notaUpdated) return res.status(500).send({message: 'No retornó objeto actualizado'})

    res.status(200).send({ nota: notaUpdated })
  })
}
```

Nota que agregué **return** en los if's, y que el if que agregué valida que te retorne el objeto actualizado. Si no te retorna el objeto, entonces no se está actualizando. Por cierto, que según tengas definido tu modelo, al hacer update a un documento, te retornará el documento antes de actualizar o el documento ya actualizado. La idea es que te retorne un objeto, si no te lo retorna es que no se hizo la operación.

Pero si sí te lo retorna, significa que sí se actualiza. Entra a la consola de mongo y haz:

```
use 'mi-db'
db.micoleccion.find().pretty()
```

para ver si te está modificando. Sólo reemplazas los valores de acuerdo a tu DB y tu colección. Esto es para no tener que instalar un programa tipo robomongo o mongobooster para consultar tu DB.

Como te decía, si no te marca ningún error, es que actualiza el doc con los mismos valores, puedes colocar esto al inicio de tu función:

```
if (!req.body.campo1) return res.status(500).send({ message: 'No se recibió valor del campo1' })
```

Así validas si estás recibiendo los valores a actualizar.

**Nota1**: colocar return en los if's de errores es para terminar de ejecutar la función, sino te continuará ejecutando el resto del código y dará error de "intentar enviar las cabeceras de retorno cuando ya han sido enviadas" (no puedes hacer más de un res.status... )

**Nota2**: los códigos http de retorno, por buenas prácticas, deben ser acorde a la causa de los mismos. El código 500 es "Error desconocido" y eso no da información suficiente. Consulta [aquí](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:C%C3%B3digos_de_estado_HTTP) para más.

Comment: Esto funciono perfecto mil gracias!

Comment: Si te sirvió mi respuesta entonces márcala :p (es como funciona Stack Overfloq)

Answer (score 0):

Accede a la base de datos con un programita que se llama [Robomongo](https://robomongo.org/) para ver los valores del registro `notaUpdated` te devuelve el registro que has modificado, sin las modificaciones hechas (pero el registro si que ha modificado), si no ha salido por el `if (err)` significa que ha ido bien y en teoría ha actualizado bien el registro.

Comment: Gracias por responder, a robomongo no lo probe todavia, pero si probe con postman y con el plugin de atom RESTclient y los dos me devuelven el registro sin cambios, yo creo que es por que **req.body** no le envia los datos nuevos, pero no se de que otro modo enviarlos.

Comment: Añade la parte en la que haces la peticion `updateNota` para ver como estas mandando la llamada.

Comment: La funcion updateNota esta en controllers/notas.js y la llamada la hago desde routes/index.js:   const notasCtrl = require('../controllers/notas')  router.put('/notas/:notaId', notasCtrl.updateNota). Aclaro que los otros  metodos para hacer get, post y delete funcionan perfectamen.

Comment: jaja ya me imagino la distribución, necesitaría el código, para ver que estas mandando.